# How to change output window text options?

Tags: visual-studio, fonts, font-size

I am using Visual Studio 2022 and I seem to have accidentally changed my output window's text font and size. This seems to have occurred after I used Google unit tests.
[my output window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRF3L.png)

I have tried resetting all my settings using the import and export settings wizard, but that does not change the output window for me. Where do I change the text font and size for my output window?